# Adding/removing role from a function in discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am having a terrible time trying to solve this. The older discord.js I had no issues but now trying to wrap my head around this new v13 is killing me. I cant use user I have to use member now??

Here is my code snippets. The first CheckMembershipStatus() is called at a certain time. This function works fine. Checks db for ending memberships then executes RemoveMembership(userid) passing userid.

My failed attempt is in the remove/add with the roles. I seen a lot of message use(other google search items for when using roles but I cant use this as I'm not sending a message?

```
function CheckMembershipStatus()
{
  consolelogging("Check Membership Status");
  con.query(`SELECT vipmembersid, discordname, membersince, memberend FROM market_expert.vipmembers;`, function(err, rows, fields) 
        {
          if (err) consolelogging(err);
          for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          //consolelogging("The discord username is: " + rows[i].discordname+ "."+" " + GetMembershipTimeRemaining(rows[i].memberend) + " days."+ " Your join date is " + rows[i].membersince +". Your memberid is " + rows[i].vipmembersid);
          if (GetMembershipTimeRemaining(rows[i].memberend) <=0){
            var mention = bot.users.cache.get(`${rows[i].vipmembersid}`);
            bot.channels.cache.get(memberstatschannel).send(`Member ${mention} membership has ended. ${rows[i].vipmembersid}`);
            RemoveMembership(rows[i].vipmembersid);
          }
          if (GetMembershipTimeRemaining(rows[i].memberend) == 1){
          var mention = bot.users.cache.get(`${rows[i].vipmembersid}`);
          bot.users.cache.get(`${rows[i].vipmembersid}`).send(displayalmostend()).catch(error => {
            consolelogging("Could not DM user!");
        }).catch(error => {
          consolelogging("SQL Error thrown: " + error);
      });
          bot.channels.cache.get(memberstatschannel).send(`Member ${mention} has one day left as VIP!`);
        }
          if (GetMembershipTimeRemaining(rows[i].memberend) == 5)
          {
              bot.users.cache.get(`${rows[i].vipmembersid}`).send(fdaysmessage()).catch(error => {
                consolelogging("Could not DM user!");
            });
            
          }
        }
        consolelogging("Memberships have been checked...");
        });
}
async function RemoveMembership(userid)
{
    ***//let member = await bot.members.fetch(`${userid}`);
    var member = bot.users.cache.get(`${userid}`);
    consolelogging("Membership has ended remove permissions." + userid);
    consolelogging(member);
    bot.channels.cache.get(memberstatschannel).send(`Member <@${userid}> membership has ended!`);
    bot.users.cache.get(`${userid}`).send(memberend()).catch(error => {consolelogging("Could not DM user!");});
    bot.channels.cache.get(freediscussionchannel).send(`Dear, <@${userid}> your membership has ended! Please use this channel to send messages for questions and a ${CEO} will respond back.`);
    //bot.users.cache.get(`${userid}`).roles.remove(viprole).catch(console.error); 
    //bot.users.cache.get(`${userid}`).roles.remove(eliteviprole).catch(console.error);
    //bot.users.cache.get(`${userid}`).roles.addRole(jointodayrole).catch(console.error);
    const role = guild.roles.cache.get(viprole)
    if(member) {
      member.roles.remove(role).catch(console.error);
      member.roles.remove(eliteviprole).catch(console.error)
      member.roles.add(jointodayrole).catch(console.error);
    }***
    con.query(`DELETE FROM market_expert.vipmembers WHERE vipmembersid = ${userid};`, function(err, rows, fields) 
    {
      if (err) throw err;
      consolelogging(`Removed User from DB. ${userid}`);
    });
    //consolelogging(`${userid} no longer in group. Remove table entry.`);
    //con.query(`DELETE FROM market_expert.vipmembers WHERE vipmembersid = ${userid};`, function(err, rows, fields) 
    //{
     // if (err) throw err;
     // consolelogging(`Removed User from DB. ${userid}`);
     // bot.channels.cache.get(memberstatschannel).send(`Member ${userid} removed from db!`);
    //});
}
```

This is my problem area:

```
//let member = await bot.members.fetch(`${userid}`);
    var member = bot.users.cache.get(`${userid}`);
    consolelogging("Membership has ended remove permissions." + userid);
    consolelogging(member);
    bot.channels.cache.get(memberstatschannel).send(`Member <@${userid}> membership has ended!`);
    bot.users.cache.get(`${userid}`).send(memberend()).catch(error => {consolelogging("Could not DM user!");});
    bot.channels.cache.get(freediscussionchannel).send(`Dear, <@${userid}> your membership has ended! Please use this channel to send messages for questions and a ${CEO} will respond back.`);
    //bot.users.cache.get(`${userid}`).roles.remove(viprole).catch(console.error); 
    //bot.users.cache.get(`${userid}`).roles.remove(eliteviprole).catch(console.error);
    //bot.users.cache.get(`${userid}`).roles.addRole(jointodayrole).catch(console.error);
    const role = guild.roles.cache.get(viprole)
    if(member) {
      member.roles.remove(role).catch(console.error);
      member.roles.remove(eliteviprole).catch(console.error)
      member.roles.add(jointodayrole).catch(console.error);
    }
```

Comment: Any thoughts? I am completely stuck maybe I am over thinking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting a guild member, but only the information cached by your client.

Instead of:

```
var member = bot.users.cache.get(`${userid}`);
```

Do:

```
var member = guild.members.cache.get(`${userid}`);
```